# how to stretch UIImage without changing centre of image in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a image which has a point at centre. now i want to stretch the image keeping the centre point always at centre. I am doing it using resizableImageWithCapInsets. But its working properly. My image size is 24*24 and the point is somewhere middle in 13pt at down.

Comment: Sorry but I suspect this is lost in translation. "stench the image" makes no sense in english. Can you describe what you want to do in another way.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the spelling mistake.

Comment: Cool. I thought maybe it was a Google translate gone wrong instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set contentMode to center.

> self.image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

Regards.

Comment: UIImage has no property like contentMode. Although we tried to set it UIImageView, but looks like not giving expected result.